# MySQL query AND OR operator Logic

Tags: mysql, database, computer-science

I'm in the middle of a project for my Comp Science project for monday, and i came across a MySQL question regarding a Query.

What I want to achieve, through words is this.

If the column **to=jake and column from=connor** OR **column to=connor and column from=jake** get the cID from that specific table.

What I have so far is this

```
 $query="SELECT cID FROM conversation WHERE to='$to' AND to='$from' OR to='$from' AND        from='$to'";
```

What is there that I can do to get this query to work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need a couple pairs of `()` to group the two conditional pairs, separated by a logical `OR`

```
$query="
  SELECT cID 
  FROM conversation
  WHERE 
      /* to Jake, from Connor */
     (`to`='$to' AND `from`='$from')
      /* OR to connor, from jake */ 
     OR  (`to`='$from' AND `from`='$to')";
```

Note: `FROM` and `TO` are both [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), and thus require quoting with backticks.

Comment: The Op should also escape the $to and $from variables

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER you don't know that he hasn't.

Comment: @Michael He failed on the parenthesis. He probably failed on escaping.   He would probably be better off with a note on escaping.

Comment: I probably did fail on escaping the variables, does it make any difference that the variables are being grabbed from Sessions, and not being used for anything else on the script? (Getting the variables and processing them in the query is the only thing being done on the page

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the backticking on the build in words. With the Backticks it works. learn something everyday!

Comment: @ronnockoch Even if the values were hard-coded into the session, get yourself into the habit of always properly escaping them before passing them into a query. Values from any user input _must_ be escaped, unquestionably.  And eventually, start using an API which supports prepared statements.

Comment: @Michael how does one escape variables and what does it do? Out of curiosity now. Feel free to tell me to go and google it if you think that would be better

Comment: **There is no fail on parenthesis**. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but I would think you need to put the to='$to' AND to='$from' (which should be from not to i guess??) into brackets??

Just realised someone else put this as i was typing it

Comment: It might be true, as it depends from which side the initial values were put into the database, it's not effieicne but it's what i understand currently.

Comment: I did say in the comment that I thought it should be from and not to!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT cID FROM conversation WHERE 
(to='$to' OR to='$from' OR to='$from') AND from='$to'";
```

Comment: I again get a MySQL error with this query
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to='5' OR to='1' OR to='1') AND from='5'' at line 2

Comment: I suggest you go with the answer above mine, its better, and follow those comments.